# val() not working in jquery mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile

I am trying to get value of selected item from dropdown menu via val() method. It works greatly when I use it in plain html withou jquerymobile divs. but when i put in into my content div it isnt working. Here is the code (only content div implemented):

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
   <head> 
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

   <title>RSS Reader</title> 

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
   <script src="main/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="main/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

</head> 
<body>
```

settings.php:

```
<?php
include('../main/header.php');
$siteNumber = empty($_GET['siteNumber']) ? 'Živé' : $_GET['siteNumber'];
?>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        Nastavenia
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <select id="training" name="training" data-native-menu="false">
         <option value="1">Živé</option>
         <option value="2">MobilMania</option>
         <option value="3">Automoto</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            function displayVals() {
            var defaultSiteNumber = $($("#training")[0]).val();
            $("p").html("<b>defaultSiteNumber:</b> " + 
                  defaultSiteNumber);
             }

             $("select").change(displayVals);
             displayVals();
        </script>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
           <li><a href = "../index.php?siteNumber=<?php echo $siteNumber;?>" data-icon="home">Späť</a></li>
           <li><a href = "settings.php?save=true" data-icon="gear">Hotovo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

After I get those values into javascript I need them to be also available in PHP variables so I can use them to create config file. Or do you think it would be simplier to create config file with javascript? It should be basic .ini with structure which is acceptable by parse_ini_file

**EDIT:** I have aded whole code including headerp.php to make sure that there is no other error causing this problem.

Comment: `$($("#training")[0])` is ugly and unnecessary since `.val()` will use the first element anyway and more important **ids are unique** so there shouldn't be more than one element in that jQuery object ever. So, simply use `$('#training').val()`

Comment: in original it was $("#training").val(); I added [0] only to try one of solutions posted there. Still none of these solves my problem.

Comment: Please do not merge solution code into your question. The question shouldn't contain the fixed code since that may "invalidate" some of the answers.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. In fact variable was there but I have forgot to ad <p></p> tags and javascript was set to print the result into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code
may it works

```
$("select").bind("change", function(event, ui) {
    var defaultSiteNumber = $(this).val();
    $("p").html("<b>defaultSiteNumber:</b> " + defaultSiteNumber);
});
```

Comment: yes it works but only in plain HTML. I cant get it working in jquery mobile divs.